# Customizing Cell: adding table view to a cell of table view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

Is it possible to add a table view on the cells of a table view? If yes then how it can be performed, provide some logics...
The requirement is that the added tableview in the cell has to be in grid format
[image]

"Clickable text In GRID Format To jump into new view" shown in figure, that region i want to make it table view... This should be scrollable also...

Comment: If someone shows you the hack, still please don't do it! It's ugly I would rather suggest having PageControl inside UITableViewCell to add multiple content

Comment: @Owl that was my initial reaction, too, but I can imagine this this tableview within a tableview notion in a variety of situations (e.g. a threaded discussion message list). Still, I would execute it as a single table view, but with custom cells, and represent the nested cells as just a different cell layout with indentation.

Comment: @RobertRyan, What I have learnt so far in theory and practical level and my respected lecturer once said, Make sure in industry we as a programmer can do so many things, because we have power to code and manipulate the dumb machine. However never forget the fact that the changes we make should be adaptable by the most dumbest entity in this world and thats "users". ;) So I would still workout a different pattern rather then OP's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my question, it can be achieved simply by creating a custom cell class. there we can place the table view and provide the reference of cell table to the custom class by connecting the table view to the custom class on xib.